# How do I get back JSON value using entityform?

Tags: 7, entities

I am using drupal 7 entityform in this case, as i want CRUD functionality with the form. Can anyone tell me how should i configure my services.

As of now i have configured it manually, selected the REST server, session authentication, Response formatters-json,   Request parsing-application/json, Resources- entity_entityform and user.

But whenever i select

Example:-'http://localhost/drupal7/test/node/2'

where 'test' is my endpoint it shows the json values for my custom article which i created for testing whereas it doesn't show up anything for my entityform

Example:-'http://localhost/drupal7/test/eform/submit/route'

where test is again my endpoint here.
Please help, do i need any special permission for entityform module like creating hook ??? 
Or should i query it in
 'function entityform_entityform_insert($entityform)'?